# Jenkins: Show date and time a test failed

Tags: python, datetime, jenkins, pytest

In our jenkins installation we can see only the duration of a test.

I am missing the date and time the test run.

Background: If the database server had a hickup at 12:15, then I know that tests which failed around this time might be a result of this "hickup".

I checked your test_result.xml which gets created by py.test (Python). But I could not find the datetime. There is an xml attribute `time="0.0899388790131"` but this seems like a duration to me.

Any chance to get the datetime for every test?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Jenkins is showing the exact time of build failing and passing within the GUI. Do you want to take it programmatically?

Comment: I would like to see the time a **test** failed. Not a **build**. All Jenkins knows about the tests are from the test_result.xml file. Since it does not contain the start time, Jenkins only knows about the duration (which is called "time" in the xml).

Comment: where do you want to see it? :)

Comment: On the page where I see if a single test has failed or passed.

Answer (score 2):

You can make pytest write the start time of each case by changing a little bit of pytest's code, only two steps needed.

**Step 1**

At the end of function `pytest_runtest_makereport` in file `_pytest/runner.py`, the original code is:

```
return TestReport(item.nodeid, item.location,
                  keywords, outcome, longrepr, when,
                  sections, duration)
```

Add a `start` parameter like this:

```
return TestReport(item.nodeid, item.location,
                  keywords, outcome, longrepr, when,
                  sections, duration, start=call.start)
```

**Step 2**

At the end of function `_opentestcase` in class `LogXML` in file `_pytest/junitxml.py`, the original code is:

```
    self.tests.append(Junit.testcase(
        classname=".".join(classnames),
        name=bin_xml_escape(names[-1]),
        time=getattr(report, 'duration', 0)
    ))
```

Add a `start` keyword, with the report's `start` attribute as its value:

```
    self.tests.append(Junit.testcase(
        classname=".".join(classnames),
        name=bin_xml_escape(names[-1]),
        time=getattr(report, 'duration', 0),
        start=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(getattr(report, 'start', 0)))
    ))
```

Now, rerun your tests and check the result xml file, there will be an `start` attribute for each test case and its value is the start time of that case:

```
<testcase classname="tests.SimpleTest" name="test_fail" start="2015-05-26 19:25:40" time="0.000133037567139">
```

Comment: OK, now the data is in the xml. But does Jenkins show this data in the web gui?